# delete right child makes parent left pointer point to nullptr

Tags: c++, data-structures

thank you for checking my question, I currently have a really basic question on operator "delete", it seems it can automatically change the pointer value to nullptr. Let me give you a example for this:

```
    template <typename T>
    void Tree<T>::remove(const unsigned& index, TreeNode<T>*& tree)
    {
        if(tree == nullptr)
        {
            std::cerr << "remove: can't find target" << std::endl;
        }
        else if(index < tree->index)
        {
            remove(index, tree->left);
        }
        else if(index > tree->index)
        {
            remove(index, tree->right);
        }
        else if(index == tree->index)
        {
            if(tree->degree() == 2)
            {
                tree->index = findMin(tree->right)->index;
                tree->value = findMin(tree->right)->value;
                remove(tree->index, tree->right);
            }
            else
            {
                auto oldNode = tree;
                tree = (tree->left != nullptr) ? tree->left: tree->right;
                delete oldNode;
    //          oldNode = nullptr;

            }
        }
    }
```

The code above is a classic searching tree remove algorithm. If the current tree only has two nodes which is root (with key equals to 3 for example) and right child (with key equals to 4 for example), so when I remove node 4, it will call remove twice and go to this line:

```
    delete oldNode;
```

And this line will delete "oldNode", which should be 4 right now. As far as my knowledge, the delete operator will just free the memory address(the address is same to the value of oldNode), which means it tells OS this address is available again. So I suppose when I print out the value of root's right pointer(root->right), I should get a address. Actually when I print out I get 0. So my question when root->right changed?

Hope I explain my question clearly. That may be a stupid question, let me known if I make any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are seeing is that the use of a pointer after the delete is undefined behavior (until c++14).

For c++14: indirection through a pointer that became invalid in this manner and passing it to a deallocation function (double-delete) is undefined behavior. Any other use is implementation-defined.

Undefined behavior basically allows the implementation to do whatever it wants with the pointer after delete (even change its value).

It looks like your implementation sets the value of the pointer to nullptr in delete.

Comment: Hi, thank you for checking.Actually I noted off "oldNode = nullptr". Sorry to make confusion, my question can be understood as "in this implementation, if a child node is deleted, when and who set the parent's right pointer to nullptr"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, but before answer, let me clarify my question. The question is asking when a child is deleted, when and who set its parent right pointer to nullptr. The answer is this function has pointer reference as argument, when call this function, the passed parameter itself will be set to nullptr. For example, when pass in root->right, the root->right can be directly set to nullptr.